# If values in Column B = specific text, insert specific text into a value in Column A

Tags: excel

Simply - if any cell in Column B contains `thisvalue` then append to the adjoining cell in Column A with `sometext`.

How is this done?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with formulas. Can you use VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Put this formula in A1, then drag down as necessary:</strike>

```
=IF(B1="thisvalue","sometext","")
```

**EDIT**

Using a the Visual Basic Editor, you can update the contents of cell A like this:

```
Private Sub UpdateColumnA()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To 65536
        If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x), "thisvalue") > 0 Then
            Sheet1.Range("$A$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$A$" & x) & "sometext"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Repeated runnings of the macro, however, will append the text again; you'll need more validation code if you don't want this to happen.

Comment: what if there are already values in col A and they need to be inserted after the current value?

Comment: @JaredEitnier Then your question really is: How do I append `someText` to the value in `An` if `Bn` contains `thisvalue`, right?

Comment: "they need to be inserted"... what is "they"?  You need to clarify your question.

Comment: Rephrasing - If the adjoining cell in Column A currently has a value set, then the inserted value (based off of the search performed on Column B) would need to be appended to the end of the current value in cell A.

Comment: This works great, need another adjustment though. Instead of searching for an exact string in Column B - how can I search for text contained in Column B?

Comment: You can use the `INSTR` function to search a string; updated my answer again.  In the future, your questions probably should be more detailed.

Comment: Agreed - I assumed this was a relatively simple procedure that a function could handle so my apologies. Thank you for the great help :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple if statement.  For example:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(thisvalue, B1)), sometext, "")
```

EDIT: The ISNUMBER(SEARCH(thisvalue, B1)) searches for thisvalue in B1, and if it finds it, it returns a number (that number being the starting index of thisvalue within B1).

EDIT #2: To append the inserted value to the end of the current value in cell A, use the CONCATENATE formula.

Example:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, sometext)
```

Answer (score 0):

copy-paste in A1 , considering that you have values in B

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("thisvalue",B:B,1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP("thisvalue",B:B,1,FALSE)&"ADDITIONAL VALUE")
```

it is saying:
if value of vlookup is is empty (if lookup returns nothing) , then show empty value ( double quotes)
but if the value of lookup returns something, then do this lookup and append  "ADDITIONAL VALUE" text to found result

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you are looking for, let me know if you are still interested and if you want me to elaborate further. This formula in cell F2: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($U$2,E:E)),$V$2,"")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($U$3,E:E)),$V$3,"")&...
where you are searching for a value that you specify in U2 across all cells in column E:E, if it finds a match it appends the value you specify in V2. To search for multiple words assigning corresponding value simply concatenate as shown as much as you like. I am able to specify hundreds of words (and corresponding values). I hope it helps.