# Excel VB - Multiple If Column Contains Strings Then

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked at a bunch of questions like this, but I have only found formulas, and VB examples that don't appear to check the values of cells in a column.

I was able to derive the following formula in Excel:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cat",R2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("5E",R2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("6",R2))), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Patch",R2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cables",R2))), "CAT 5E Ethernet Cables")
```

The problem is that this formula only checks for 1 out of 500 possible values. This is not productive. Plus, I have to make it one big formula when I check the entire row, because if I don't, the formula overwrites the result of the previous formula...

So, Visual Basic... I think I may have better luck scripting some kind of **IF ELSE** or **CASE** statement. I just do not understand how to do this in excel. I need to achieve the same thing as the formula above, but instead of checking for one set of conditions,

I need to check for multiple, and populate the **S** & **T** columns based on the result of each set of conditions.

I found this webpage that just mentions Excel and shows a VB **IF - ELSE** statement. How can I make this statement check Excel columns?

I tried the selected answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527787/if-values-in-column-b-specific-text-insert-specific-text-into-a-value-in-colu) with no luck:

```
    Private Sub UpdateCategories()
        Dim x As Long
        For x = 1 To 5000
            If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x), "cat") > 0 And InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$B$" & x), "5e") > 0 Then
                Sheet1.Range("$T$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$T$" & x) & "CAT 5E Ethernet Cables (Test)"
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No no worries. There are strings in two different columns of the worksheet that I can check for to determine a Department and a Category (for our website). Example: If "cat" and "5e" are present in B2, and "Cables" is present in R2, then the Department (Column S) is "Networking Cables" and the Category (Column T) is "CAT 5e Ethernet Cables"

Comment: Basically I need to write logic that checks for keywords in two columns, and based off the results, assign a Department and Category to each row for our website. Ultimately, the spreadsheet will be used for an RMS import.

Comment: There are about 500 categories. I need to check for about 3-4 keywords to determine the appropriate classification so about 1500

Comment: There are a ton of rows to check. I can narrow down the conditional statement quite a bit with a preliminary check for what the possible categories are.

Comment: Realistically, the final number of conditional checks will be about 400

Comment: At some point you will have to manually indicate which categories go with what. The program can't guess. So I suggest you make a table in a sheet with every category, and what keywords refer to them. It will be long, it will be boring. After this, you can have a macro that loops over your values and for each value, go to the table, loop over it, and try to find the corresponding category. I don't see any other way.

Comment: I would like to eventually have a script that can screen all incoming vendor excel spreadsheets and conduct this logic to classify each product, but one step at a time right?

Comment: If you only have a few keywords, why not check for those and if you find one of those, go to a different check for the other options. It's really very difficult to construct something without seeing what your data looks like.

Comment: I understand. Here is the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PkNUL5Dh9QakVzb3VSNnRZTnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And here is a list of my departments and categories (and subcats): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18dw2NOVnwmbI7I1CEEBLwlXQ1bWlq3XYd4naDpH-K1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The first spreadsheet is for a vendor that only sells networking-related products, so a check for all of the possible categories and departments is not necessary. Mainly just the categories under "Networking"

Comment: Sounds like @DavidGM is right, you might even be better off with a database

Comment: @David GM - I could do that. What would the macro look like to iterate through the table? Foo bar example?

Comment: It will probably be a bit lengthy so I will write it as an answer.

Comment: That would help me so much. I could totally put a keyword table together. Comma separated keywords in one cell, category in another and then another table with department - category mappings.

Comment: So i would use keywords to assign a category, and then insert a department based off each category.

Comment: @Raystafarian I agree. It would do the job so I can import all of these products into our RMS database...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you choose the route of using a data table sheet to compare to your string.

You would need to have a sheet looking like this (Maybe this is not what you want because I didn't thoroughly understand how your data looks like but the idea remains). You could have sub-category if you want, as well as category, in a third column.

column A | column B

keyword          |category

CAT              |ATX Cases

5e               |Mini-ITX Cases

important words  |MicroATX Cases

...

This would need to be filled manually. I'm not sure about the amount of data you're looking at. It can be pretty rapid if you can copy/paste stuff efficiently, depending on the form of your data.

When you have that, loop using this code. I assume the data table is in Sheet1, columns A and B and the values are in Sheet2, column A.

```
dim listLength as integer 'number of values to look at
dim i as integer
dim dataLength as integer 'number of keywords
dim j as integer
dim keyword as string
dim value as string

listlength = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'assuming you start on row 2
datalength = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'assuming you start on row 2


for i = 2 to listLength + 1
    value = Sheet2.Range("A")(i)
    for j = 2 to dataLength + 1
        keyword = Sheet1.Range("A")(j)  
        if instr(value, keyword) <> 0 then
 ' what happens when the keyword is present goes here
        end if
    next j
next i
```

Comment: If no keyword is found, you can do something particular. If you find a certain keyword you can look for a next one but that would have to be in your table as well...

Comment: Right on. I will start here. If you were curious, here is an excel file with  all three sheets (Vendor Data (with preview of desired end result), Keyword - Category matches, and Category - Department matches). It will be my test dummy. It is a slimmed down version of my original data of course.

Comment: I think the part I would need the most is the ability to use multiple keywords with an implied "AND" operator. So that I could list multiple keywords like "Cat, 5e, Cable" that is checked as "If Cat && 5e && Cable Then mark as 'CAT 5E Ethernet Cables' (category)"

Comment: Oh. So create a strin`g (CatString), then where it is written to write the code, write CatString = Catstring & " " & keyword. Every keyword will be added to the CatString. While looping, it will add Cat. Then it will add 5e. Then it will add Cable. In order of apparition (this may not be the order you want, but eh. You'd have to order the data table accordingly if that's important to you).

Comment: I have to say I am at work so I will not open your excel file right now, but keep me posted if you have more question (Stack Overflow is allowed because they think I am always asking questions ^^)

Comment: I will see what I can come up with on my own. I couldn't get your script to run, but that is surely just due to the fact I am a greenhorn when it comes to Excel VB. I'll figure it out! Thanks David!