# Excel: Removing column A value from repeating list in column B?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In column A I have a series of numbers in numerical order. Each number is in its own cell.

In column B I have a cell that contains all of these numbers. Each row in column A has a copy of this cell in column B.

For example:

A1: 100

A2: 200

A3: 300

B1: 100 200 300

B2: 100 200 300

B3: 100 200 300

I need a way to remove the column A value from the list in column B, so that each list in column B does not include the value in its column A.

For example:

A1: 100

A2: 200

A3: 300

B1: 200 300

B2: 100 300

B3: 100 200

Basically the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527787/if-values-in-column-b-specific-text-insert-specific-text-into-a-value-in-colu). How can I make this happen, preferably without VB?

[Here's the entire dataset on Pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/WQvsxecQ)

Comment: Ready to use helper column if you don't want to use VBA?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the spreadsheet is wide open for use.

Comment: So I assume we can insert a column in between A and B, so you'll get new comun B. ???

Comment: In cell C1, use this formula and copy down: `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" "&B1&" "," "&A1&" "," "))` and column C will contain the results you want.

Comment: Yes, I can add more columns.

@tigeravatar No dice, it just replicates the list from B1 in every cell. I should probably note that the values in the list aren't separated by spaces or commas, they are separated by CHAR(10) newlines.

Comment: I tried using `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")` but when the numbers in the B list reached 1000, it removed the 100 (A1's contents) and left me with 0, 1100 became 1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Based on a comment that numbers are separated by CHR(10)

Assuming your data is in range A1:B3.
Insert once column in between so you'll have three column with data in column A and C with blank column B in between.
Place this formula in cell B1 and drag it down.

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C1,$A1,""),CHAR(10)," "))
```

And you'll have your result in column B like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This almost works, but because it removes all instances of 100 (in this example) and not specifically "100", results like 1000 become 0, 5100 become 5, etc. Any ideas?

Also, if it helps, the number's position in the list will always be equal to its row number, ie 100 is in row 1 and is the first value in the list, 200 is in row 2 and is in the number 2 value in the list, etc.

Comment: You should provide better test data. Can you update your question with one?

Comment: I got all rows except for first and last with your new requirement. Still working on it.

Comment: I've added a link to the entire dataset in the original post. Thanks, I can do the first and last manually no problem!

Comment: Try this formula `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C1,CHAR(10)&$A1&CHAR(10)," "),CHAR(10)," "))`. Like I said it won't work for first and last row. I am still working on complete one

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the value of A1 in cell b1 for blank value, it doesnt work? Did you try it?

```
Range("A1").Select
Value1 = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Replace What:=Value1, Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Looking the comments, i understood your problem... The replacement gets some part of the value...

Comment: If you transform text to column, delimitating it by spaces, you will get the full number, maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar idea to other comments, I have a bit of a crazy nested formula but maybe worth a try?

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" "&SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(10)," ")&" "," "&A1&" "," "))`

... replacing the CHAR(10) just for the comparison, and adding spaces on either side of each value to target the instances of e.g. 100 in 1002

Comment: Oh no wait, just spotted the comment about CHAR(10)... will have another look and edit this!

Comment: Edited - seems to work on my test spreadsheet, assuming I've understood your data set correctly :)